# Cross-Database Query on Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, azure, azure-sql-database

I am using Azure SQL Database and I have two databases. I want to select one table data on the first database and merge into another (conditional) table of second database.

Is there any SQL solution to solve my problem?